# Can the android Emulator in eclipse can be shutdown? how? need it for testing my Alarm Manager auto start at boot

Tags: android, eclipse, alarmmanager, intentservice

I dont have an actual Android phone, and i want to test Alarm, but i dont know if its the code that has error, or the emulator doesnt do the way like an actual phone in terms of booting.

the Autostart Code is from here:
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

The code doesnt give me error, the simple alarm manager and service is OK, but the autostart of the alarm is not working, i hope its only on the emu, wish it will work in an actual phone. The code below is from the above-mentioned thread, and it also the one that i uses.. i'd put it because maybe the code are the problems

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

And this is the on-boot trigger

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb -e shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

type this, after going to android sdk/platform-tools through command line

this will send an artificial BOOT_COMPLETED action

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "platform-tools" folder in your "android-sdk" folder through **command line**. Type following commands:

`adb devices`

-- Here it will list the current emulator you have started earlier. If the emulator is dislayed, which will, then type below command.

`adb reboot`

-- This will reboot the emulator without touching any button on on the emulator.

Comment: after i execute adb reboot, nothing happens, though the cmd doesnt create a new line and the emulator stops working...maybe its still processing? is restarting it takes long?

Answer (score 0):

You can long press `powerOff` button which is provided in Emulator then it will show you different options like `Silent Mode`,`Airplane Mode`, `Power Off`. In other case you can restart your emulator. This way you can check your `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Comment: how can i restart it? just close the emu and start it again? the Boot_completed broadcast doesnt work in this case..

Comment: where your application is get installed on internal or external? and add  `android:enabled="true"` in your receiver.

Comment: Its ok now, i use the "adb -e shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"..thanks anyway

Comment: @mcr619619 you should answer to your own question so question could be close